# How can I switch on the data type of an object field?

Tags: java

I have a long switch statement that I'm trying to make more efficient.
It parses an xml feed and populates a Java object using the xml values. 
There are maybe 30 fields so it's kind of tedious to write a switch case 
for each field.

```
switch (currentTagName) {
    case "longitude" :
        observation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(parser.getText()));
        break;
    case "elevation" :
        observation.setElevation(Integer.parseInt(parser.getText()));
        break;
    case "observation_time" :
        observation.setObservation_time(parser.getText());
        break;
```

You can see, the only difference in how each case is handled is due to the type of data I'm working with.

I'm trying to figure out the syntax for doing something similar to this (pseudocode):

```
//get the data type of this variable, somehow or other
String inputType = Observation.getMethodInputType("set" + currentTagName); 

//switch on that data type
switch(inputType) {
    case "Integer":
        observation.set{currentTagName}(Integer.parseInt(parser.getText()));
        break;
    case "Double": 
        observation.set{currentTagName}(Double.parseDouble(parser.getText()));
        break;
    case "String":
        observation.set{currentTagName}(parser.getText());
        break;
}
```

It's just that my Java syntax is pretty rusty, I'm not sure what the correct way is to do this (or if you even can), 
especially for the set{currentTagName} part and getMethodInputType() (is that a thing?).

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution will be pretty unmaintainable. Java has few popular methods of parsing xml in compact way (without tedious string operations).

You should check:

- [JAXB](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) (recommended) which provides good domain encapsulation and very readable code
- [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) which is semi readable and semi fast
- [SAX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) which is very fast and least maintanable

For JAXB you will have to create object/objects which will recreate xml structure and conversion will happen automatically for you.

Comment: Wow, I forgot the extent to which Java has a library for everything. I think JAXB is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `switch`. Make an interface for conversion of `String` to an object by type, populate a `Map<Class,Converter>` with converters of appropriate type, and use converters from that map to parse your input.

```
interface Converter {
    Object convert(String s);
}
private static Map<Class,Converter> converterForClass = new HashMap<>();
static {
    converterForClass.put(Integer.TYPE, s -> Integer.parseInt(s));
    converterForClass.put(Double.TYPE, s -> Double.parseDouble(s));
    converterForClass.put(String.class, s -> s);
    converterForClass.put(Long.TYPE, s -> Long.parseLong(s));
};
```

Now you can convert `String`s to `Object`s of the appropriate type like this:

```
Object a = converterForClass.get(Integer.TYPE).convert("123");
```

Here is a demo that uses reflection to access the field:

```
static class Demo {
    public int a;
    public long b;
    public String c;
    public double d;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a+":"+b+":'"+c+"':"+d;
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Object a = new Demo();
    Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("a", "123");
    data.put("b", "123456678789898");
    data.put("c", "HELLO");
    data.put("d", "123.456");
    for (Field f : Demo.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        String str = data.get(f.getName());
        Object r = converterForClass.get(f.getType()).convert(str);
        f.set(a, r); // Call set(target, objValue) instead of setInt, setLong, etc.
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

[Running demo.](http://ideone.com/LG1FQJ)

Comment: Though a nice solutions, the problem with calling different setter methods (with different names) for different tags stays. Perhaps you improve your solution with a bit of fairy dust aka reflection which makes a lookup for the field to put the data into.

Comment: @ThomasJunk The problem of having to call different methods for different types goes away completely, because there is a `set` method that takes an `Object` (see demo). Of course if one insists on calling different methods based on the type, instead of converting and returning the object the lambda could take a field and a target as additional parameters, and do the setting internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert it to an object and get its class name using:

```
((Object) yourVar).getClass().getName()
```

Then you can use it in your switch statement:

```
String typeName =  ((Object) inputType).getClass().getName();

switch(typeName) { 

   case "Integer":      

            observation.set{currentTagName}(Integer.parseInt(parser.getText())); 
   break; 

   case "Double":

             observation.set{currentTagName}(Double.parseDouble(parser.getText())); 
    break; 

    case "String":

              observation.set{currentTagName}(parser.getText()); 
    break;
 }
```

Take a look at [How to determine the primitive type of a primitive variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361492/how-to-determine-the-primitive-type-of-a-primitive-variable) for further information.

Comment: This solution would work but this may not be a good use case for the switch statements.

Comment: @ChakladerAsfakArefe Yes I completely agree that `switch` case is not the best solution here, but I was just rectifyingthe OP code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert either the int and double into a string, and then use one if statement. Use the following syntax:

```
Integer.toString(i)
//Makes an integer into a string
```

and

```
Double.toString(i)

//Makes a double into a string
```

Once you have everything as a string, compare strings. This way the variable type is the same, and it makes the code much easier to deal with.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little Java-8 library called [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml), that might be of help to you. It's open sourced on Github, and available on Maven Central.

You can create an `ObjectParser` that will pick out a value from an `XPath`, and put it into a `JsonObject` as an attribute. Then it uses Jackson's json-mapping to instantiate your class.

Read up on Jacksons [Json to Object mapping](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes), to see how to best fit it into your classes.

*Example:*

```
<root>
    <entry id="1">
        <observation>100</observation>
        <longitude>150</longitude>
        <observation-time>15 sec</observation-time>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Lets say your area of expertise is birdspotting, and this is your class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class BirdSpotting {
    public Integer id;
    public Integer observation;
    public Double longitude;
    public String observationTime;
}
```

You can create a (reusable) `ObjectParser`, and `apply` it to your xml.

```
public List<BirdSpotting> getData(Document inputXml) {
    Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();

    ObjectParser<List<BirdSpotting>> parser = 
        parsing.arr("/root/entry", parsing.obj()
            .attribute("id", "@id")
            .attribute("observation", "observation", parsing.with(Integer::parseInt))
            .attribute("longitude", "longitude", parsing.with(Double::parseDouble))
            .attribute("observationTime", "observation-time")
    ).as(BirdSpotting.class);

    List<BirdSpotting> spottings = parser.apply(inputXml);
    return spottings;
}
```

You can also parse into a single `Birdspotting` object by dropping the `parsing.arr()`part. Your `parser` will then be of type `ObjectParser<Birdspotting>` (without the `List`).

*Output*

```
BirdSpotting [id=1,observation=100,longitude=150.0,observationTime="15 sec"]
```