# Java using instanceof method on primitive type gives compiler error

Tags: java, instanceof

I am learning Java, and I do not understand why the following code does not compile without error:

```
public class SecondClass{

public static void main(String[] args){
    int number = 45;
    if (number instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("Not a String!");
    }
  }
}
```

Why do I get an error in my conditional operation? The `instanceof` should return `true` or `false` right? In this case there should be `false` since `number` is an `int`, but this code does not compile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361492/how-to-determine-the-primitive-type-of-a-primitive-variable Further explanation here. instanceof is only for use on Objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [section 15.20.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> The type of the RelationalExpression operand of the instanceof operator must be a reference type or the null type; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

In your case, the case of the RelationalExpression operand is `int`, therefore you get a compile-time error.

Even if you had an expression of type `Integer`, you'd then run into:

> If a cast (§15.16) of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression could never be true.