# How do you take an object out of array and use instanceof on it?

Tags: java, arrays, int, instanceof

I am trying to make the following code or something similar to work:

```
static String[][] arr = new String[4][4];
static int[][] arr2 = new int[4][4];



for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = "1";
            arr2[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]);
            if(arr2[i][j] instanceof int){
                System.out.println("Works");
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead the IDE marks it red and gives an error "Inconvertible types; cannot cast int to int".

Can somebody help?

Comment: int[] is not int

Comment: The array is declared as 2d int array, so any index that you'll check is of type int, further `instanceof` doesn't work with primitive types. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361492/how-to-determine-the-primitive-type-of-a-primitive-variable what do you *really* want to check?

Comment: can `instanceof` even be used for plain old value types like char,int,boolean?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing how is `arr2` actually declared and what you expect to do with your check. `instanceof` operator doesn't work with primitives in first place, in addition array type rules doesn't allow casting between array types so what you think to do probably won't work.

Comment: Smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question. Please show real code and make your question much more concrete so that it can be well answered.

Comment: @jack "can't cast int to int" answers your question

Comment: You can't use `instanceof` with primitive types. It wouldn't make any sense to.

Comment: @alfasin: no, that would rise an error at `arr2[i][j]` since subscript `[]` operator is not allowed on an `int`. Actually it would be "array required but found `int`".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the limited information you provided.
You will have to change every place where it says `int` to `Integer` because `instanceof` cannot check for primitive types. Your code would look like this:

```
static String[][] arr = new String[4][4];
static Integer[][] arr2 = new Integer[4][4];


for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = "1";
            arr2[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]);
            if(arr2[i][j] instanceof Integer){
                System.out.println("Works");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can always know if Integer.parseInt worked because if it didn't, it would throw an exception.

Comment: This is completely pointless. Why teach OP to do something so obviously wrong?